# How to use facebook API to post to my own page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I had the ability to post from my website to my page some time ago, it seems there have been some changes made to the API since then now when I use the below snippets I get the error message

```
{"message":"(#100) Only owners of the URL have the ability to specify the picture, name, thumbnail or description params.","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"AsGjV6ebkihnC60tRtHM4f3"}
```

Code

```
function postToFeed(id, desc, name) {

    var page_id = ************;
    var app_id  = ************;
    FB.api('/' + page_id, {
        fields : 'access_token'
    }, function(resp) {
        console.log(resp);
        if (resp.access_token) {
            FB.api('/' + page_id + '/feed', 'post', {
                message : desc,
                link : 'https://link',
                name : name,
                from : page_id,
                description :'',
                access_token : resp.access_token
            }, function(response) {
                if (!response || response.error) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(response.error));
                } else {
                    alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, like the error message suggests, this changed some time ago. See the respective section

> Custom Link Page Post Image

in the docs for more information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.3/page/feed

You can of course also just remove the custom description parameter.

Comment: I just removed the description as you suggested